# Error in Running Django tests in visual studio

Tags: django, visual-studio, unit-testing

My tests are running fine in terminal but while  trying to run tests in visual studio i got error of :
Error of django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded

My Visual studio Folder settting file is:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/home/aditya/Maximl/Blast4/Server/syncopsenv/bin/python3.6",
"python.unitTest.pyTestEnabled": false,
"python.unitTest.nosetestsEnabled": false,
"python.unitTest.unittestEnabled": true,
"python.unitTest.debugPort": 3000,
"python.unitTest.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": true,
"python.unitTest.pyTestArgs": ["."],
"python.unitTest.unittestArgs": ["-v", "-s", ".", "-p", "*test*.py"]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio doesn't go via `python manage test`. So you need to explicitly call django.setup() first. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590167/unit-tests-fail-to-load-with-django-in-visual-studio)